# magento attributes on list products

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

I am new to magento, and I need to display the product attributes on product list in the quickview popup of every product. please help,ASAP!

Comment: please share your code...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
```

Comment: that display the name of the product!

Comment: Yeap. Do you want to show all or some attributes?

Comment: I don't think you understood. I was needing the product attributes, not the product names. I answer a few hours ago, if you look up, the sollution for my question.
thanks you!

Comment: i got it. But, just to let you know, the name is an attribute as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();?>
    <div class= "specifications">
        <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
                $value   = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                $s_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product);
                echo $s_value;
                echo $value;
            }
        } ?>
```

this works for me :)